# How can I run python script in node.js project

Tags: python, node.js

**What I want to do:**

I would want to create 2 endpoints /servers and /items. Both endpoints should send json from GET request, but for /servers endpoint, I have python script that scrapes data from the website and outputs json file and here is a problem, because I can't run this python script as I don't have required imports and don't really know how to add them using node.js.

server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const { dirname } = require('path');
const appDir = dirname(require.main.filename);
const fs = require('fs');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');


const PORT = 8080;

const options = {
  pythonPath: process.env.PYTHONPATH
};

app.get('/servers', (req, res) => {
  // Run the serversScrapper.py script and update the serversList.json file
  PythonShell.run(`${appDir}/serverScrapper.py`, options, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
      return;
    }
    
    // Send the updated serversList.json file as the response
    res.sendFile(`${appDir}/serversList.json`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
  });
});


app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${appDir}/itemsList.json`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});

// Run the script every 2 minutes
setInterval(() => {
  PythonShell.run(`${appDir}/serverScrapper.py`, null, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
}, 2 * 60 * 1000);


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server up at 8000'))
```

I've copied and pasted only script file to the project folder, so that might be an issue, but I think there should be a way for node.js to automatically start python script and import required libraries (bs4, requests, json)

**error log:**

```
PythonShellError: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
    at PythonShell.parseError (/rbd/pnpm-volume/eb08c55a-3afc-4775-99f3-8543de0493fc/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:295:21)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/rbd/pnpm-volume/eb08c55a-3afc-4775-99f3-8543de0493fc/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:190:32)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/eb08c55a-3afc-4775-99f3-8543de0493fc/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:182:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
File "/app/serverScrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup {
  traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n' +
'  File "/app/serverScrapper.py", line 2, in <module>\n' +
    '    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\n' +
    "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'\n",
  executable: 'python3',
  options: null,
script: '/app/serverScrapper.py',
  args: null,
  exitCode: 1
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you that it cannot find the module bs4, so that means it is not installed yet. You can do that with `pip install bs4`

Comment: I've pasted this in terminal before, it has been installed, but still doesn't work. Maybe the issue is that the application I am creating this server on (glitch.com) uses python 2.7 as after executing pip I have following warning:

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.